# How to link a dropdown button content with a pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dc.js

I have created a pie chart with a dropdown `hover` button. The thing is Im not able to link it with the chart. Please help me clear this issue.

```js
   

    <html lang="en">

    <body>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css"/>
    </head>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_content"  style="margin: 35px 0px 0px 0px;color:black;width:250px;height:200px;background:#ffffff;border:1px solid black;">
    <div id="billplan">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bill Plan


    <head>
    <style>
    .dropbtn {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: black;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 10px;
    border: box;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin:7px 0px 0px -130px;
    }

    .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    min-width: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin:30px 0px 0px -130px;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 2px 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" style="float:left;">Select<span class="caret">    </span></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#$20">$20</a>
    <a href="#$30">$30</a>
    <a href="#$40">$40</a>
    <a href="#$60">$60</a>
    <a href="#$80">$80</a>
    </div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </div> 

    </div> 
    </div>


  <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/js/custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dc.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">



    var billplanchart = dc.pieChart("#billplan");
 

    d3.csv("data/billplanchart.csv", function(error, experiments) {

    var ndx           = crossfilter(experiments),
     planrate        = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.plan_amount;}),
     billplandimgroup    = planrate.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return    (Math.round(d.Count));});
    planamount= ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.plan_amount;});

    billplanchart
    .width(250)
    .height(120)
    .dimension(planrate)
    .group(billplandimgroup)
    .slicesCap(5)        .colors(d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#71b77f","#0f63bc","#FFDA33","#205936","#0a3887","#E51F30"]))
    .on('pretransition', function(chart2) {
     chart2.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d){
            return  Math.round(dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle -  d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100)*10)/10+ '%';
        })
    });
    billplanchart.render();



    d3.select('#$20').on('click', function(){
    planamount.filter("$20");
    dc.redrawAll();
    });
    d3.select('#$30').on('click', function(){
    planamount.filter("$30");
    dc.redrawAll();
    });
    d3.select('#$40').on('click', function(){
    planamount.filter("$40");
    dc.redrawAll();
    });
    d3.select('#$60').on('click', function(){
    planamount.filter("$60");
    dc.redrawAll();
    });
    d3.select('#$80').on('click', function(){
    planamount.filter("$80");
    dc.redrawAll();
    });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you limit your code to the problem at hand ?

Comment: yes I have limited according to the problem.

Comment: can you at least fix the snippet?

Comment: Please, check now.

Comment: sory man can't help you without a working demo

Comment: Yeah, kind of hard to tell without a working demo. There are [fiddles and blocks you can fork to get started here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/CONTRIBUTING.md#issue-submission-guidelines).

Comment: Do the menu items have no effect, or the wrong effect?

Comment: They have no effect